# Access the name of agent who received the call in a Queue

Tags: freeswitch

Is there any way by which i can receive the information about which agent received the call in queue and what is the duration of call and other information. 
I read about the variables that hold this information like cc_agent, cc_queue_answered_epoch etc but how can i access them through freeswitch API in Lua OR it must be evaluated from dialplan only by setting action application to "luarun" with required data.! I am simply forwarding the call to queue
    Session:execute("callcenter","Sales")

Basically what i am trying to do is recording all this information in a database after agent hangup the call. Any clue or a direction will be very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you have your callcenter app setup, you could parse the CDR data for the following:

```
cc_agent
```

That value should be something like:

```
agent007@pbx.widgetets.local
```

Given this, you can you simple use regex in your scripting language and you'll be able to quickly see the agent that answered the calls.

Comment: I know its too late,  i forgot to accept your answer :)